# Changing Activity screen when the app is not running

Tags: android

How can i change the screen of an activity when pressing any button on an android phone that takes one away from the running app.

I'm trying to get a blank screen to show up on the "recents" screen, instead of a snapshot of the app.

[image: Valid XHTML]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this option and check if it helps you meet your need.

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Add this to your activities in the application manifest if you do not want the app to be shown in the recent apps list. One drawback is that you would not be able to resume the app from the Recents list. Not sure if this is what you need.

The other way is to have a 'Blank Activity', which you start when your actual activity pauses. You can then finish the 'Blank Activity' on its Resume. This way, you will have your app shown on the Recents list, but with a blank screen.

Comment: I understood he wanted the app to be present,but shown as a white screen instead of the usual snapshot

Comment: The android:excludeFromRecents idea would have been great, but i need the app to be shown.  I was hoping there would be an easier way than to make another activity for this.

Comment: You may have an opaque overlay, if activity seems costly.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to change the onpause() or onclose() functions of your app. they are the last thing android execute before leaving,therefor you can change the aspect off your app just before you leave it

EDIT : 
Maybe if you create PopupWindow and set it to full screen, and color black when exiting no preview would be shown, but app would still be running (idea of user DjDexter5GH) in the onpause() and onclose() functions. therefgor,when you leave,a black(or whatever you want) screen is pushed in front
you can then close it in the onrestart(is it called this?)

Answer (score 0):

You can call finish() for activity but that will kill activity. I think that will leave blank screen. Or destroy(). Try both respond with results.

Comment: but you cannot load them again

Comment: or I believe the whole point of the recent screen is to get back to the app without starting it again, si your solution would block this

Comment: Maybe if you create PopupWindow and set it to full screen, and color black when exiting no preview would be shown, but app would still be running.

Comment: good idea,I added it to mine(the onpause() which open when switching) and I think we have a good answer